# Error no such file or directory, multer package

Tags: node.js, npm, multer, wordpress-rest-api

Getting this error in postman while uploading an image through multer

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\\adarsh\\API\\uploads\\2022-11-29T17:23:07.574Zdownload1.jpg'"
    }
}
```

Code of it.

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Tried writing the above code

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the way you are providing the destination path, try with '/uploads'